# Sql Order by using different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table having data like for eg.:

```
CategoryID      CategoryName

1               Beverages
2               Condiments
3               Confections
4               Dairy Products
```

I want the query to return the data like this..

```
 CategoryName

 Beverages
 Dairy Products
 Condiments
 Confections
```

..
please suggest how to achieve this.

Comment: Please show some effort, post some code, what have you tried, etc, etc...

Comment: what kind of logic are you looking in this sorting order?

Comment: @Yani yes i tried using something like "ORDER BY CASE WHEN" conditions etc but unfortunately couldnt get it.

Comment: However @Vignesh's hint did the trick..Thank you all my friends..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT CategoryName 
FROM Table1
ORDER BY CASE WHEN CategoryName LIKE 'B%' THEN 1
              WHEN CategoryName LIKE 'D%' THEN 2
              WHEN CategoryName LIKE 'C%' THEN 3
         END ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess there is no way to manipulate order by in that way, that you get the list like you want it to. So the easiest way to achieve your order is to add another column with a sortingindex and order by that column instead.